# Bash if variable is an integer

Tags: bash, variables, if-statement, integer

I'm trying to write an if statement in bash that will exit if the variable supplied is not an integer. I will eventually be nesting this if statement within a while loop.

When I do run this I am getting an syntax error.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $f1 != ^[0-9]+$ ]
    then 
        exit 1 
    fi
```

Comment: by integer, are you including negative integers or only positive?

Answer (score 4):

I have always like the integer test using the equality `test` construct:

```
[ $var -eq $var 2>/dev/null ] || exit 1
```

If `var` is not an integer, the equality fails due to the error generated. It is also POSIX compliant as it doesn't rely on character classes or the bash `[[` construct.

Answer (score 2):

You better negate the condition like this:

```
if [[ ! "$f1" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then 
  exit 1
fi
```

note the `[[` and `]]` syntax for the regular expressions, together with `!` to negate it. Then, we use `=~` for regexs.

#### Test

```
$ r=23a
$ [[ ! "$r" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && echo "no digit" || echo "digit"
no digit
$ r=23
$ [[ ! "$r" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && echo "no digit" || echo "digit"
digit
```

Comment: thank you very much can you explain to me why this is important and what this command do to make this work correctly ?

note the [[ and ]] syntax, together with ! "$var" =~.

Comment: In case you want negative integers just add a -? (optional '-') to the start of the regex as such: [[ ! "$f1" =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]]

Comment: @thisguy this is well explained in [The conditional expression](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression). Specifically when it talks about `<STRING> != <PATTERN>` as `<STRING> is checked against the pattern <PATTERN> - TRUE on no match`.